# Unable to mount external hard disk in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, ntfs, ubuntu-13.10

When I tried to mount via terminal:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /mnt
```

it shows the following message:

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /mnt
[sudo] password for ****: 
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

What does it mean? And how do I resolve this? My Seagate 2 TB HDD is new and initially it worked.

---

I am sorry but still after your suggestion again it shows like this:

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt 
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0). 
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error 
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware.
In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice.
The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). 
Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.
```

Comment: Please check your formatting, you can't dump everything in one paragraph. Indent code by 4 spaces or use the {} button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sdb is the device name.... to mount the partition itself, you need to mount /dev/sdb1, assuming that sdb1 is the first partition on the disk(and probably the only one). Good luck.